# Adding htmlattributes to DropDownList helper changes behaviour

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

Prior to MVC 5 the DropDownList was scaffolded in my Razor Edit View as:

`@Html.DropDownList("EntityId", String.Empty)`

But now the equivalent (post MVC 5) is scaffolded as:

`@Html.DropDownList("EntityId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

I want to add the `htmlAttributes` to keep the UI consistent, but the DropDownList no longer works as expected for a nullable EntityId `(int ? EntityId)`. The problem is that the default item is set to the first item in the list if EntityId is null. I want a blank item if the id is null, and the appropriate selection if not.

PS. My controller builds the list as follows: 
`ViewBag.EntityId = new SelectList(db.Entities, "EntityId", "Name", EntityId);`

Comment: Does your model have a property your binding to? (you should not have the same name for the model property and the `ViewBag` SelectList property)

Comment: Yes it does, could that be causing the problem? Not sure why I ever did this, but I suspect it is like that in a lot of my code. I have just seen your reply below, and will try this out back at work tomorrow. Thx

Comment: Just noticed why I use the same property name for both the model and ViewBag - it is because it is scaffolded that way in the controller by default - something to be aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the strongly typed helpers. If your model has a property `int? EntityId`, then in the controller

```
ViewBag.EntityList = new SelectList(db.Entities, "EntityId", "Name")
```

Note the ViewBag property should not be the same name as the model property, and the 3rd parameter of 'SelectList` is not required.

Then in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EntityId, (SelectList)ViewBag.EntityList, "--Please select--", new  { @class = "form-control" })
```

If `EntityId` is `null`, the first option will be selected, otherwise if `EntityId` matches the value of one of your options then it will be selected.

Comment: Do you mean **ViewBag**.EntityList not Model.EntityList?

Comment: Yes I do :) will update in a momement (I always use view models and hate `ViewBag`)

Comment: That did it thanks - the name of the ViewBag property didn't seem to make any difference though. Is there a specific reason why the ViewBag property and model property names can't be the same? Just curious.

Comment: I was wrong - if the ViewBag property name is the same as the Model property name, then the selected item is **not** selected, and this was the source of my problems from the outset.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `@HTML.DropDownList` to

```
@Html.DropDownList("EntityId", (SelectList)Viewbag.EntityList,String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })`
```

Comment: This worked too thanks, once I added a cast for the SelectList (edited your post). Thanks.